# Cloudflare not redirecting to HTTPS

Tags: web-hosting, https, cloudflare

I set it up, and set "Automatic HTTPS Rewrites" to "ON", BUT this still not redirecting me to the https by default when the page is requested via http... accessing the page manually by putting https at the url is working fine.

Any ideas how to solve this, please?

Comment: What _flavour_ of SSL do you have with Cloudflare?

Comment: what do you mean by that, please? I selected the Flexible option and it says Active...

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant: "Flexible", "Full" or "Full (Strict)". (That might be irrelevant anyway as it happens - the "Flexible" option is only encrypted to CF, the connection from CF to your site is still unencrypted.) I notice on the [CF site](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/227227647-How-do-I-use-Automatic-HTTPS-Rewrites-) that "To determine which URLs do not have HTTPS support, we use data from EFF’s HTTPS Everywhere and Chrome’s HSTS preload list, among others." - that may have a bearing on whether CF will rewrite the URL. Most sites do this manually in the server config.

Comment: Hm... So, I guess my server doesn't. Anyway I can do it by my end(as a user of the hosting without access to the server config)? Or perhaps there's any further reading on that... I'm just totally lost with it.

Comment: Or by server config, you actually meant to use, say `.htaccess` file? If so, again, where do I find info what to put in it?

Comment: I've read about the "HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)" on the CF site and seems like this is the option to go with in order to rly force https... But it says it requires some knowledge etc... I wonder, how really this complex? Any short info will be great :)

Comment: Ok, so seems like HTST is not really a great idea... looking forward to your help folks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are having problems with the "Automatic HTTPS Rewrites" Cloudflare option then it maybe that CF is unable to determine whether your site/resources are HTTPS enabled. From the CF docs on [Automatic HTTPS Rewrites](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/227227647-How-do-I-use-Automatic-HTTPS-Rewrites-):

> To determine which URLs do not have HTTPS support, we use data from EFF’s HTTPS Everywhere and Chrome’s HSTS preload list, among others.

To unconditionally redirect all users to HTTPS the preferred method would seem to be to create a page rule. From the CF support doc: [How do I redirect all visitors to HTTPS/SSL?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170536-How-do-I-redirect-all-visitors-to-HTTPS-SSL-)

> The most effective means of redirecting visitors to HTTPS when using Cloudflare is using a [page rule](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218411427). While you can also redirect to HTTPS using configuration at your origin, page rules are processed at our edge, resulting in a quicker response and reduced requests to your server.
>
> The "Always use HTTPS” action is the simplest option to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS.

The following steps describe the process of using [page rules](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172336-How-do-I-create-a-Page-Rule-) (which will behave as a 301 redirect):

> [Cloudflare Page Rule 301 Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS](https://www.bybe.net/cloudflare-enforce-ssl-redirect-http-https/#cf-301-redirect)
>
> 1. Login to Cloudflare
> 2. Select your
>    site using the dropdown menu found in the upper left corner
> 3. Click the Page Rules icon at the top of the screen
> 4. Click the Create Page Rule button
> 5. Enter
>    http://*example.com/* but obviously changing the domain with
>    yours.
> 6. Under “Then the settings are:” click + Add a
>    Setting
> 7. Click the dropdown list, find and click option
>    “Always Use HTTPS”
> 8. Finally click Save and Deploy

However, many users still use their own server config (by that I literally mean either the main server config, virtual host or `.htaccess` file) and mod_rewrite (Apache) to perform the redirect. However, on the CF "Flexible SSL" option you need to be careful of a redirect loop, since your site is still serving content over HTTP to CF, so ordinary HTTPS checks cannot be applied. (The CF "Flexible SSL" option just protects the connection from the end-user to CF, not the connection from CF to your server.)

So, something like the following near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

With "Flexible SSL" the `HTTPS` server variable is always `off` (since your site is serving content over HTTP), but Cloudflare should be setting the `X-Forwarded-Proto` HTTP request header as the request passes through Cloudflare's servers. Keeping the first condition ensures it should work regardless of whether you are using CF or not. If you are always going to be behind a proxy (CF) then you can remove the first condition.

> ...so seems like HTST is not really a great idea...

If you are committed to HTTPS then HSTS is a great idea. However, it is a one-way ticket. You will not be able to (easily) revert back to HTTP.

Comment: Thanks! Just to make it a little bit clear for my self: the `%{HTTPS} off` - the first line - is there for CF to get the http content(the original one), correct?

Comment: And one more thing: at the bottom line, I need to change only the domain name, right, without touching the `$1` and `[R=301,L]`?

Comment: Actually, if you are behind CF then that first condition (`%{HTTPS} off`) is not strictly necessary. CF sets the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header (used in the second condition). However, I would say it's good practice to keep that first condition - if you moved your site or changed CF's "Flexible SSL" option then you would get a _redirect loop_ without it. And yes, change just `example.com` to your _canonical_ hostname.

Comment: On Apache, the `HTTPS` server variable contains the string "on" or "off" depending on whether the request is for HTTPS or HTTP respectively. If you had a SSL cert installed directly _on your server_ then this would be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy for your help! It's much clear now. I've also was able to change the page rules by my own and seems like this is actually the way to go! without even the `.htaccess`. However, I'm really concern if I could do this multiple times for multiple domains (I have 3 :) ), because there's a limit for 3 rules, I just don't understand if it's by domain or absolute. Also, I don't have SSL on my end(server), but only the one provided by CF.

Comment: It's very strange tho, because this page rules just doing the exact same thing as the default setting of forcing the HTTPS("Always use HTTPS"), but with page rules they are actually working... very odd. I wonder why this is happening, I mean, if the default "Always use HTTPS" doesn't work, then how can it work by page rules...

Comment: "if the default "Always use HTTPS" doesn't work" - Do you mean the "Automatic HTTPS Rewrites"? I think this does something a bit different (and can be used together with the canonical redirect above). If, for instance, you were linking to external (possibly third party) resources via HTTP then I think this option allows these requests (in the HTML source) to be updated automatically by CF if these are available over HTTPS. Ideally, you would update the site yourself to ensure that all resources are fetched over HTTPS. (I think?)

Comment: No, not the "Automatic HTTPS Rewrites" of the "Page Rules", but the "Always use HTTPS" at the "Crypto" section. At CF site it says its not recommend to update at the server(my end) end, because of the use of resources - kinda make sense. So I think it's not really ideal way, but perhaps I'm wrong?

Comment: I'm making my life harder :) It is actually the "Automatic HTTPS Rewrites" at the "Crypto" settings... My bad. And yes, I understand it know what you meant at the prev. message. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Check your wordpress (or whatever you are using) general settings that the domain is set with https in the editor/admin options.